# Вывод в консоль u_char *

Tags: c++, windows

Есть переменная типа u_char *, размер не ясен. Как ее вывести в консоль в HEX формате?

Comment: Вывести ее содержимое - указатель?

Comment: Не указатель а содержимое

Comment: То, на что указывает указатель? Но вы же сами пишете "размер не ясен". Так сколько именно байт выводить?

Comment: выводить по одному символу пока не встретиться `\0`?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Вам надо явно и отдельно получать размер массива и знать тип хранящихся в нём данных.

Дело в том, что указатель `u_char *` (а также `char *` и `void *`) как правило означает, что начиная с указанного места идёт буфер с сырыми данными. Что в этом буфере и какого оно реального типа и размера известно только тому, кто этот буфер заполнил.

К примеру, данные по указателю, указывающему на буфер `uchar[]: 2a 4b 00 5a 8d ff 00 00 ...` можно интерпретировать кучей способов. Например:

1. Массив из N `uchar`-ов неопределённой длины. Причём нельзя сказать, где заканчиваются элементы и начинается другая область памяти.
2. Массив из N `int`-ов неопределённой длины.
3. Нуль-терминированная ASCII-строка `K*` и мусор за ней.
4. Нуль-терминированная UTF16-строка из каких-то трёх символов.
5. Какая-то структура. Например, `struct {ina a; char b; short c;};` (с выравниванием полей или без него).